# Excel - Stuck with VBA code to replace sheet names in date form in formulas

Tags: excel, vba, properties

As the perhaps confusing title says, I'm writing a set of automated tools for a workbook and I've hit a roadblock.

I have a function that generates a new sheet and assigns it the current date as the name, in the format of "dd-mm-yyyy" (without quotation marks), and another that updates all required formulas in the new sheet.

There is a column that calculates the difference between the values in a column between the current and previous sheet. Upon running, the code executes and replaces the names but for some reason designates only the year as the sheet name, not the entire date. This results in an invalid reference error.

Example:
Previous sheet name: 23-5-2019

Current sheet name: 25-5-2019

The changed formula in the current sheet should be: =C3-'23-5-2019'!C3

But it instead becomes: =C3-23-5-'2019'!C3

The code for the replacement is below:

```
Sub FormulaUpdate()

range("D2:D100").Replace 
What:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count - 2).name, 
Replacement:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count - 1).name, 
LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't replicate this in code, it works as expected with the below when I name Sheet( 3) as 23-5-2019 and Sheet(2) as 25-5-2019

```
Sub Macro3()
to_replace = Sheets(3).Name
replace_val = Sheets(2).Name
    Cells.Replace What:=to_replace, Replacement:=replace_val, LookAt:=xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

I'd suggest debugging step by step and confirming the values for the text to find and replacement values just before it takes place.

Also confirm that your new sheet has been created prior to doing the find / replace.

Hope that helps.